# openfire add user to group

Tags: xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I've read many Posts about adding a user to a group programmatically on openfire dev forum.
Unfortunately, none of them worked for me.
I can programmatically create users via `UserManager.createUser()`. After I successfully created a new User, I want to add him to a group 'users'.

The group already exists so I was trying to use following code:

```
public void addUserToGroup(User user) {
   Group group = GroupManager.getInstance().getGroup("users");
   JID jid = new JID(user.getUsername());
   group.getMembers().add(jid);
}
```

I've found that code snippet in an answer [HERE](https://community.igniterealtime.org/message/102105).

Then I've tried to use this example [Java Code Example org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.Group](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.Group) (Example Number 9), even if I wouldn't understand how this event will add a new member to a group.
Like I said, none of them worked.

Can you please give information about "how can I add a group member to a group?"

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: i actually searched the web and have a coding problem. i dont know what i did wrong.

Comment: may I ask a "larger" snippet to check where are you implementing the addUserToGroup method?